# Move lines containing numbers to new file

Tags: bash, grep

I have list

```
dasfdsaf
afddt4fd
asdw5h6ufdh
sfds2dsddf2nu
dsfnjufsd443ajisdfaij
sdfjid654sij
asfdnu7sdfui
sdfmii
```

I want to move all lines containing numbers in it to new file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: This code will **copy** lines with a digit in them into the output file: `grep -E [0-9] input > output`.

When you say move, do you also want to remove those lines from the input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `grep` has the `-P` option:

```
grep -P '\d' old_file > new_file
grep -vP '\d' old_file > temp
mv temp old_file
```

If `-P` isn't supported, use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to match digits:

```
grep '[0-9]' old_file > new_file
grep -v '[0-9]' old_file > temp
mv temp old_file
```

Comment: This would move all the lines containing numbers to a new file using `bash` and `grep` so I don't get why this answer isn't useful. Some explanation for the downvote would be nice so I can understand what I need to improve.

Comment: No downvote from me. You answered before dogi sec showed his amount of research.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Cyrus! Ok, I haven't answered many `bash` / `grep` questions in the past and knowing the threshold "when to answer" is always tricky since different programming communities develop their own. My answer _does_ however answer the question so a downvote just seems wrong.

Comment: I am really sorry! I am new to bash and I dont have enough resources to learn (only 2 hours of 100kbps internet and 10 hrs power) a day. thank you for answering. It worked

Comment: @dogisec Great, you're welcome!

Comment: Hey Ted, any idea how to do same operation for "s3" stringed lines?

Comment: @dogisec Do you mean lines that contains the text `s3`?

Comment: ya lines containing s3

Comment: @dogisec Then just change `\d` (or `[0-9]` if you used that) to `s3` in both `grep`s.